# Switch validator on component

Tags: jsf, conditional-statements, validation

How can i switch my validator in a component dependence on a boolean.

I have a selectBooleanCheckbox and when its true i want use FirstValidator else i want use SecondValidator. I found nothing about this "special" case.

Nothing special only for example code:

Xhtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head>

</h:head>

<h:body>
<h:form>
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{testBean.firstValidator}"/>
    <h:inputText>
        <f:validator validatorId="FirstValidator" />
    </h:inputText>
    <h:commandButton value="Test" />
    <h:messages />
</h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

Bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable{
private boolean firstValidator;

public boolean isfirstValidator() {
    return firstValidator;
}

public void setfirstValidator(boolean firstValidator) {
    this.firstValidator = firstValidator;
}
}
```

Validator1:

```
@FacesValidator("FirstValidator")
public class FirstValidator implements Validator{

@Override
public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
        Object value) throws ValidatorException {
    String valueAsString = (String) value;
    if(valueAsString.contains("a")){
        throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("Fail!"));
    }
}
}
```

Validator2:

```
@FacesValidator("SecondValidator")
public class SecondValidator implements Validator{

@Override
public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
        Object value) throws ValidatorException {
    String valueAsString = (String) value;
    if(valueAsString.contains("b")){
        throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("Fail2!"));
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set/disable the validator depending on checkbox's value. You only need to make sure that you pick the checked value as available during view build time (which runs during restore view phase). So you definitely can't use the model value `#{testBean.firstValidator}` for this (which is only set during update model values phase). You'd need to determine the HTTP request parameter instead. It's empty if the checkbox is unchecked, otherwise it's not empty.

First bind the checkbox component to the view (not to a bean!) via `binding` attribute:

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox binding="#{checkbox}" ... />
```

This way the request parameter can be dynamically obtained as `#{param[checkbox.clientId]}`.

Now you can use *either* conditional setting of validator ID:

```
<f:validator validatorId="#{empty param[checkbox.clientId] ? 'firstValidator' : 'secondValidator'}" />
```

*Or* conditional setting the validator's `disabled` attribute:

```
<f:validator validatorId="firstValidator" disabled="#{not empty param[checkbox.clientId]}" />
<f:validator validatorId="secondValidator" disabled="#{empty param[checkbox.clientId]}" />
```

---

Note that I altered the validator IDs as per Java instance variable naming conventions. You also don't do as follows in normal Java code, right?

```
Validator FirstValidator = new FirstValidator();
```

Comment: thank you ! Good and helpful balus answer, again :))